# How can I derive the content of my select view from records in ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have this:

```
App.LoginRegisterController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  init: function () {
    this.set('products', this.store.find('product'));
  },
  subscriptionOptions: function () {
    return this.get('products').map(function (product) {
      return {id: product.id, title: product.title};
    });
  }.property('products')
});
```

Then in my template:

```
{{view "Ember.Select"
content=subscriptionOptions
optionValuePath='content.id'
optionLabelPath='content.title'}}
```

However subscriptionOptions only get called once before the `products` are populated. If I change the template to:

```
{{view "Ember.Select"
content=products
optionValuePath='content.id'
optionLabelPath='content.title'}}
```

The data gets populated correctly, but I need to insert an option into the select that isn't related to any of the models, so I need to populated it with references. How can I get the select to update from `subscriptionOptions` as `products` change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I needed to use `@each` on the property and `get()` when accessing the title for it to show up properly.

```
App.LoginRegisterController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  init: function () {
    this.set('products', this.store.find('product'));
  },
  subscriptionOptions: function () {
    return this.get('products').map(function (product) {
      return {id: product.get('id'), title: product.get('title')};
    });
  }.property('products.@each')
});
```